# OR Condition when right outer join is used

Tags: sql

I am trying to learn SQL and wondering if something like this possible.

```
Select * 
from RDInfo RD
right outer join RDCollection RDC 
    on (RDC.RDInfoID = RD.RDInfoID and RDC.IsReceived = 1 
        and RDC.IsRenewed = 0) or -- RDInfoID not in table RDC
```

I am trying to get data from RDCollection if it satisfies 3 conditions written in the braces if not RDInfoID does not have a record in RDC table. This is in Sql 2005.

I hope i am clear. I am not sure if this is the right away. Thank you very much for the help. Thanks!

So here, All Employees may or may not have a record in Department, so in that case, how can

Comment: So, if no match is found you want the column from RDC to return the text "RDinfoID not in table RDC"?

Comment: @octern Exactly as you said! But it should return a row with all RDC columns as NULL.. Is it even possible?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what a left join does. See Chris's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a left join instead of a right.

```
Select *  
from RDInfo RD 
left outer join RDCollection RDC  
on (RDC.RDInfoID = RD.RDInfoID and RDC.IsReceived = 1 and RDC.IsRenewed = 0)
```

By using *left outer join* entries from RDInfo are returned regardless of whether or not there's a match for RDCollection. When there isn't a match the columns from RDCollection contain nulls.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Select * 
from RDInfo RD left outer join
     RDCollection RDC 
    on RDC.RDInfoID = RD.RDInfoID
where (RDC.IsReceived = 1 and RDC.IsRenewed = 0) or rdc.RDInfoID is null
```

If you mean where "RDInfoID not in table RD", then use a right outer join and check for rd.RDInfoId:

```
Select * 
from RDInfo RD right outer join
     RDCollection RDC 
    on RDC.RDInfoID = RD.RDInfoID
where (RDC.IsReceived = 1 and RDC.IsRenewed = 0) or rd.RDInfoID is null
```

Comment: "RDInfoID not in table RDC" is the case, @Gordon! If there is no record in RDC with RDID, get NULL for all columns of RDC. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should only do join if you are only interested in the rows satisfying the condition else you could go with left or right join depending on which row you want from which table.